# Как мне собрать 4 маленьких треугольника, чтобы сделать большой треугольник?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, svg

Я хочу создать на фоне треугольник с изображениями,  путем соединения 4-х треугольников, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу сделать эту коллекцию форм изображения треугольника?

```css
.block {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid 20px;    
    float: left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.top {
    margin-left: 38px;
}
.top .left {    
    border-color: transparent green green transparent;
}
.top .right {    
    border-color: transparent transparent green green;
}
.bottom .left1 {    
    border-color: transparent red red transparent;
}
.bottom .mid1 {    
    border-color: blue blue red red;
}
.bottom .mid2 {    
    border-color: blue purple purple blue;
}
.bottom .right1 {    
    border-color: transparent transparent purple purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <div class="block left"></div>
    <div class="block right"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
    <div class="block left1"></div>
    <div class="block mid1"></div>
    <div class="block mid2"></div>
    <div class="block right1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/30760173/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Как я уже упоминал в комментариях, это может быть случай, когда `SVG / canvas` является лучшим решением.

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people/" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="img2" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="img3" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="img4" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M150,0 225,150 75,150" fill="url(#img1)" />
    <path d="M0,300 75,150 150,300" fill="url(#img2)" />
    <path d="M75,150 225,150 150,300" fill="url(#img3)" />
    <path d="M150,300 300,300 225,150" fill="url(#img4)" />
</svg>
```

**Edit**: как указано в комментариях ниже, добавлен некоторый код, чтобы показать, как манипулировать элементами (щелкните по двум треугольникам, и их изображения будут меняться):

```js
var step = 0;
var $prev;

$("path").on("click", function() {
    switch (step) {
        // if it's the first step: save the current element for later
        case 0:
            step = 1;
            $prev = $(this);
            break;
        // if it's the second step: swap images and start again
        case 1:
            step = 0;
            var aux = $prev.attr("fill");
            $prev.attr("fill", $(this).attr("fill"));
            $(this).attr("fill", aux);
            break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="300">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1DGN.png" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="img2" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEK3H.png" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="img3" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/phSLq.png" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="img4" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Zn4.png" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M150,0 225,150 75,150" fill="url(#img1)" />
    <path d="M0,300 75,150 150,300" fill="url(#img2)" />
    <path d="M75,150 225,150 150,300" fill="url(#img3)" />
    <path d="M150,300 300,300 225,150" fill="url(#img4)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Что-то сервера раздачи картинок барахлят сегодня,- то есть изображения, то нет. Придется картинки на сервер SO перекладывать

Comment: сильно тормозят и не запускаются ресурсы с `http`, а с `httpS` чуть лучше.

Comment: @UModeL Да, сейчас на наш сервер перекину картинки. Сегодня с утра уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой, видимо у них что-то не в порядке http://lorempixel.com

Comment: Я через ruSO на imgur.com загружаю то, что может пригодиться здесь. Не маньячу, но всё же. Вот, может пригодится для отладки - https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png

Comment: @UModeL имено его и имел ввиду